# How can i save icon files

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I have 5 buttons that show the .exe icon and name after they are added by the user.
Now i can save the name and path of the added application after the users closes the app, so when the app starts again the user still see the added applications.

But i can't find anything about saving the icon from the exe file to the settings file.
Is this even possible (don't tink so)? And what is a better way to do this?

Comment: Do you want to save the links to the exe file or the icons themselves?

Comment: The icons themselves, i can get the icon name and path, but on application close i can only save the name and path. I need to know how i can save the icon.

Comment: Why do you need to save the icon itself? If you know the path of the icon, you can just load up the icon from that path on startup.

Comment: Thanks aj_r that could really be a good solution i'm going to try that :)